# Szemeredi's regularity lemma for countably infinite graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Consider the following version of Szemeredi's regularity lemma found in the Fox and Lovasz paper, "A tight lower bound for Szemeredi's regularity lemma", arXiv: 1403.1768v1 [math.CO] 7 Mar 2014:

> For any $\epsilon$ $\gt$ 0 there is a (least) $M$($\epsilon$) such that any graph ($V$, $E$ ) has has a vertex partition into at most $M$($\epsilon$) parts with irregularity at most $\epsilon$$|V|^{2}$.

The universal quantifier 'for any graph' certainly holds for any finite graph, but can this form of the regularity lemma hold for countably infinite graphs as well?  If not, what would be the correct form of the regularity lemma for countably infinite graphs (if any)?

Since I have mentioned the Fox/Lovasz paper, I have a question of a purely personal interest: does their "tight lower bound" keep the regularity lemma from being provable in $EFA$?

Comment: One can replace the vertex set $V$ by any finite measure space and have exactly the same lemma (mutatis mutandis) with basically the same proof. If one uses an infinite measure it is unclear how even to formulate what regularity means rigorously.

Comment: @TerryTao:  thank you. Very helpful.  Possibly silly question:  if one were to formulate the infinite measure in nonstandard analysis, would that help?

Comment: For hyperfinite graphs one can do this (using Loeb measure) and this is indeed a useful framework to place regularity lemmas. For countable graphs one could play around with finitely additive probability measures perhaps (Banach means) though I am not sure what applications this would have.

Comment: @TerryTao:  any references regarding the Banach means you are referring to?

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/05/11/generalisations-of-the-limit-functional/https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/05/11/generalisations-of-the-limit-functional/

Comment: @TerryTao:  Thanks.

Comment: @TerryTao:  Regarding my question, would it make sense to try to apply Szmeredi's Regularity Lemma to the Rado graph $R$, since all finite and countably infinite graphs are induced subgraphs of $R$?

Comment: How would you propose to define regularity in this context?

Comment: Well, isn't the Rado graph universal with respect to this property?

Comment: (cont.) "The only countable partition-regular graphs are the complete graph, the null graph, and $R$, namely, only these three graphs are such that any finite vertex coloring yields a color whose induced subgraph is isomorphic to the original graph"?   For a countably infinite graph, wouldn't that qualitative property suffice to define regularity ( and couldn't one express Szemeredi's Regularity Lemma qualitatively in terms of vertex colorings or have I misunderstood the term "partition-regular")?

Comment: Partition regularity is a completely different concept from the notion of epsilon regularity used in the Szemeredi regularity Lemma, despite the appearance of the word “regularity” in both terms.

Comment: I see, thanks.  Is there a way to generalize the notion of epsilon-regularity so that finite graphs would participate in (so to speak) in being epsilon-regular and the countably infinite graphs would participate in the generalization so the generalization so the Szemeredi Regularity lemma would hold for finite graphs and its generalization (with the generalization of epsilon-regularity) would hold for countably infinite graphs (one should not be expected that the aforementioned generalization should hold for countably infinite graphs since there is no relation between standard integers and

Comment: (cont) nonstandard integers in $PA$  (after all, what nonstandard integer would 1+2+3+4+..., be, anyway)?

Comment: Mentally cross off, "so the generalization", in the comment beginning with, "I see, thanks."  Thanks.

Comment: Also cross off the "in" after the parenthesis in "(so to speak)", in the same comment as well.  Again, thanks.